# Given a n number of digits and a sum x, how can I count the amount of ways you can obtain x from the sum of the digits?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

My problem originally was "Given a number of two digits, in how many ways can you obtain 12 as the sum of its digits?".

I could find the solution by counting:

1. 93: 9 + 3
2. 84: 8 + 4
3. 75: 7 + 5
4. 66: 6 + 6
5. 57: 5 + 7
6. 48: 4 + 8
7. 39: 3 + 9

Then I found 7 as the answer. But I realized that if the number of digits were 3, the counting would get too big already, so I would like to know if there's a way to generalize this problem and its solution.

Comment: Just to be clear, in your mind, digits go from 0 to 9? So when $n=3$ and $x = 1$, you can write $x = 0 + 0 + 1$? And when $n = 3$ and $x=28$, there is no solution because $9+9+9<28$?

Comment: yes! digits go from 0 to 9

Comment: But can you have a *number* 007 ?

Comment: @trueblueanil yes, if n = 3. Also 070 and 700